# Correctness of adding "one" before a plural form (like people) or collection

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

We are struggling to decide on a name for our company. Our preferred choice happens to be onefora.com. As a non-native English speaker, I am worried if it sounds odd to native speakers. Would "one fora" be as valid as "one people"?

Can we in any way grammatically justify calling our company "one fora". (If it helps, we are making software for forums).

Comment: "Onefora" sounds quite odd to me (AmE). You can name your company anything you like. "Fora" to me sounds like the plural of "forum", so it sounds as odd as, perhaps, "one oranges".

Comment: Yes, it sounds odd. _One_ is not used with plural nouns. Note that _people_ is not a plural noun—it is a **singular** noun that just happens to refer something that consists of several things. Its plural is _peoples_, and you cannot say _*one peoples_, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Fora" is indeed a plural for "forum."  I only see it on Internet as a plural for a discussion forum, but freedictionary.com lists it as a legitimate plural for other types of forums.

To be grammatically correct, you'd need to be "oneforum.com."